# Sending nodejs module to the core browser

Tags: node.js, apostrophe-cms

I'm tring to implement the nodejs module Readline to get input from Chrome console. So far I've created a module that creates a browser side module using self.apos.push.browserCall('always', 'apos.create("my-module")'); I thought I could just write const readline = require('readline'); in the js file that got pushed to the browser but it doesn't work, which makes sense since this is the file that is sent to the browser and doesn't have access to nodejs. Is there a way to make this work, so I could type in the console apos.my-module and inmediately display a label and an input stream?

Comment: The readline module is not designed for browser-side use. What do you mean by an "input stream" in the context of the browser - what is your actual goal?

Comment: I mean capturing input data in the javascript console, I'd like to be able to call it in a function so I could type in the console "apos.getInput();" and it'd open the readline input. My whole goal is simple, I'm refactoring apostrophe-login, instead of using a form in /login, I'd like to simply open the javascript console, type apos.login() and type my username and password, then it'd reload the page on success or print console.log("incorrect user or pass"); on failure.

Comment: My current workaround is using apos.login("username", "password"); and sending those arguments via post with jquery, it works but not the way I intended, I can't even hide the password while typing.

Comment: The javascript console is a debugging tool, it is not intended for this purpose and I don't think hiding input is even possible there. You should be thinking about designing the right UI for your needs if it is not a login form, but you can't use the console for this.

Comment: Thanks Tom, you're right, I ended up using prompts and activating them on ALT + l key events and using apos.isDefined(apos.adminBar) to make sure the user is not already logged in.